# Design patterns for a mathematics visualisation tool in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, decorator, observer-pattern

I am writing a visualisation tool for creating mathematical animations for a YouTube channel that I want to create. The tool will eventually have similar functionality to [Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim), except that I am implementing everything using OpenGL in C++.

I have already developed the base functionality for visualising models via the OpenGL pipeline. However, I am a bit stuck with designing an animation manager to conveniently *choreograph* multiple models over the timeline of an animation. This is because I am still developing an intuition for when to apply specific design patterns in different contexts. So far, I have applied the *Observer Pattern* as follows - I have a `Visualiser` class which holds pointers to `Model`s and, amongst other things, keeps track of the global timestamp of the animation. Each model holds a shared pointer to the `Visualiser` object that points to it, to be able to *observe* the timestamp of a given frame and compute a local time parameter for the lifetime of the model (e.g. for the purpose of moving the model along a parametrised trajectory). I would like to equip each model with the following *actions* over its lifetime (`Model` is an abstract base class with these virtual methods):

1. Scaling.
2. Translating
3. Rotating about an axis
4. Ramping up - i.e. visualising the construction of the model at the beginning of its lifetime (e.g. tracing the perimeter of a circle)
5. Ramping down - i.e. visualising the destruction of the model at the end of its lifetime.
6. Transforming to a different model (e.g. smooth transformation from a circle to a square)
7. Transforming from a different model (instead of *ramping up*)
8. Transforming to a different colour
9. Other actions that could be added in the future...

I would like to implement an interface (in `Model`?) that allows me to implement an arbitrary combination of the above actions over a `Model`'s lifetime. Each `Model`'s lifetime will be specified using a *start* and *end* time corresponding to the global timestamp in `Visualiser`. Each *action* will be given a *start* time, a *duration* for the action (except for ramp up/down, which will only be given a duration), and lambda functions for fine-grain control over the action's independent parameters (e.g. model scaling factor based on a sigmoid function). I am leaning towards using the *Decorator Pattern* here, but I am not sure how to adapt it to this context.

I would appreciate any advice on which design patterns would be best for the above scenario.